# WPF MVVM linking selection of two tree views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am working on a WPF application where I am attempting to link the selection of two `TreeView`. One `TreeView` is a flattened view of my view models and the other `TreeView` maintains the hierarchy of the view models. The problem I have run into is getting the `TreeViewItem` to expand to reveal the selected `TreeViewItem`. My binding for the `IsSelected` seems to work fine but my binding for the `IsExpanded` doesn't seem to work. When I debug it the property changed seems to bubble up and cause the is `IsExpanded` to be set but nothing changed in the UI. This applications styles are based on the [MSBuild Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com/) but I am trying to accomplish everything I can in a MVVM way and the way the trees are linked in the MSBuild Log Viewer does not seem to follow a MVVM design.

Here is the code I have tried and an image of what the application looks like. The left hand side shows a flat list of all the nodes that contains what I searched for and the right hand side has all the nodes in a hierarchical view.

[image]

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="NugetDependecyTree.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:dependencyviewmodels="clr-namespace:NugetDependecyTree.DependencyResolver.ViewModels"
             xmlns:dependencybehaviors="clr-namespace:NugetDependecyTree.DependencyResolver.Behavior"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="VersionExplicitStroke" Color="MediumAquamarine" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="VersionInferredStroke" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SearchResultStroke" Color="OrangeRed" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContainsSearchResultStroke" Color="LightCoral" />

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="VersionExplicitBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="Honeydew" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="VersionInferredBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="MistyRose" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="LightCoral" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <!-- Tree View Items -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="DependencyHeirarchyTemplate" DataType="{x:Type dependencyviewmodels:DependencyTreeItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Content}">
                <TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dependencyviewmodels:DependencyViewModel}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="icon" Width="14" Height="11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="3,3,6,3" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="3,0,3,0" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="version" Text="{Binding Version, StringFormat={}({0})}" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DependencyInferred}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource VersionInferredBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource VersionInferredStroke}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="ToolTip" Value="Inferred Version" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DependencyInferred}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource VersionExplicitBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource VersionExplicitStroke}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="ToolTip" Value="Explicit Version" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" >
            <Setter Property="dependencybehaviors:SelectedItemBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DependencyHeirarchyTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="NugetDependecyTree.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NugetDependecyTree"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1028">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Splitter, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="240"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,3,0" DataContext="{Binding SearchViewModel}">
            <!-- Left Hand Search -->
            <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Key="Return" />
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                </TextBox>

                <TreeView Name="SearchTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" Background="{DynamicResource Theme_ToolWindowBackground}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DockPanel>

        <GridSplitter Width="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding CentralViewModel}">
            <!-- Main Tree View -->
            <DockPanel x:Name="CentralTreeViewDockPanel" DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{Binding TreeView}" >
                <TreeView Name="CentralTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

SelectedItemBehavior.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace NugetDependecyTree.DependencyResolver.Behavior
{
   public class SelectedItemBehavior
   {
      #region IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected
      public static bool GetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(TreeViewItem treeViewItem) => (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty);

      public static void SetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value) => treeViewItem.SetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty, value);

      public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(SelectedItemBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged));

      private static void OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         TreeViewItem item = depObj as TreeViewItem;
         if (item == null)
            return;

         if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

         if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OnTreeViewItemSelected;
         else
            item.Selected -= OnTreeViewItemSelected;
      }

      private static void OnTreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         // Only react to the Selected event raised by the TreeViewItem
         // whose IsSelected property was modified. Ignore all ancestors
         // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Selected fired.
         if (!ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
            return;

         TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
         if (item != null)
            item.IsSelected = true;
      }

      #endregion // IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected
   }
}
```

DependencyTreeViewItemModel.cs

```
using NugetDependecyTree.Models.MainWindow;

namespace NugetDependecyTree.DependencyResolver.ViewModels
{
   public class DependencyTreeItemViewModel : TreeViewItemModel<DependencyTreeViewModel, DependencyTreeItemViewModel>
   {
      public bool IsSelected
      {
         get
         {
            DependencyViewModel model = Content as DependencyViewModel;
            if (model != null)
               return model.IsSelected;

            return false;
         }
         set {
            DependencyViewModel model = Content as DependencyViewModel;
            if (model != null)
               model.IsSelected = value;

            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      public bool IsExpanded
      {
         get
         {
            DependencyViewModel model = Content as DependencyViewModel;
            if (model != null)
               return model.IsExpanded;

            return false;
         }
         set
         {
            DependencyViewModel model = Content as DependencyViewModel;
            if (model != null)
               model.IsExpanded = value;

            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      public DependencyTreeItemViewModel(DependencyTreeViewModel treeView) : base(treeView)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

DependencyViewModel.cs

```
using NugetDependecyTree.DependencyResolver.Models;
using NugetDependecyTree.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace NugetDependecyTree.DependencyResolver.ViewModels
{
   public class DependencyViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
      ...

      public List<DependencyViewModel> Dependencies { get; } = new List<DependencyViewModel>();

      private bool _isSelected;
      public bool IsSelected
      {
         get => _isSelected;
         set
         {
            DependencyTreeItemViewModel parent = Parent as DependencyTreeItemViewModel;
            if (parent != null) 
               parent.IsExpanded = true;

            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      private bool _isExpanded;
      public bool IsExpanded
      {
         get => _isExpanded;
         set
         {
            _isExpanded = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      ...
   }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
using NugetDependecyTree.Properties;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace NugetDependecyTree.Models
{
   public abstract class ViewModelBase : IChangeTracking, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      protected ViewModelBase()
      {
         PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnNotifiedOfPropertyChanged);
      }

      protected bool SuppressChange { get; set; }

      protected void OnNotifiedOfPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e != null && !SuppressChange && !string.Equals(e.PropertyName, nameof(IsChanged), StringComparison.Ordinal))
            IsChanged = true;
      }


      ...

      #region Interface
      #region INotifyPropertyChanged
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
      #endregion

      #region IChangeTracking

      public virtual bool IsChanged
      {
         get
         {
            lock (_notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot)
            {
               return _notifyingObjectIsChanged;
            }
         }

         protected set
         {
            lock (_notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot)
            {
               if (!Equals(_notifyingObjectIsChanged, value))
               {
                  _notifyingObjectIsChanged = value;

                  OnPropertyChanged();
               }
            }
         }
      }
      private bool _notifyingObjectIsChanged;
      private readonly object _notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot = new object();

      public virtual void AcceptChanges()
      {
         IsChanged = false;
      }
      #endregion
      #endregion
   }
}
```

Comment: When you set IsSelected you have to walk all the way up the parents and set IsExpanded to true

Comment: @SirRufo I am setting it on the parents model here `DependencyTreeItemViewModel parent = Parent as DependencyTreeItemViewModel;
            if (parent != null) 
               parent.IsExpanded = true;` which then causes it's `OnPropertyChanged()` to  be called. This was my first though but I am seeing that it is walking up the parents when I debug it.

Comment: I see that you do that, but you have to do it also for the parent of that parent and the parent of that parent and the parent of that parent ... until that parent has no parent - and you should only do that if IsSelected value is **true**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `IsExpanded` property for every parent up to the root.

I had to guess with the code because you did not show where and how the Parent property is defined. But you should get the idea

```
namespace NugetDependecyTree.DependencyResolver.ViewModels
{
   public class DependencyViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
      ...

      private bool _isSelected;
      public bool IsSelected
      {
         get => _isSelected;
         set
         {
            if (value)
            {
                // expand all parents up to root
                DependencyTreeItemViewModel parent = Parent as DependencyTreeItemViewModel;
                while (parent != null)
                { 
                   parent.IsExpanded = true;
                   parent = parent.Parent as DependencyTreeItemViewModel;
                }
            }
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: There were two issues. One issue what that I was not updating the IsExpanded through each of the parents. The other issue was, as you pointed out, that I had not posted how I was setting the parent. After I fixed those issues it works now. Thank you!